# How Puppet handles manifests in terms of processes?

Tags: linux, puppet, process, fork

I want to find out how Puppet handles manifests: in master process or Puppet forks it to execute in child process?

It necessary for me to know what exactly do `puppet master` while handling manifests, because I need to push some default configurations into `"container"` running on `"client"` machine. That `"client"` node is the slave of host with `puppet master`, but `"container"` does not have `puppet`. And then I have to apply these configs on `"container"` without using `puppet`

Comment: i dunno... u changed your question.... try setting the master to debug logs

Comment: @nandoP, information about clients and containers is not so important. It's important for me to know about `puppet` behavior while processing manifests for nodes. If your answer contains exactly that info about my question, so my question may be marked as solved

Comment: so you should mark it solved then :D

Comment: @nandoP, okay, than you very much =3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my understanding is that the puppetmaster does not handle manifest execution on clients at all, it simply pushes the manifest out to puppet client upon request. on the puppet client, running manually shows whats going on:

> strace puppet agent -t

it appears to be a serial process execution, with no forking.  in fact, forking would subvert all the necessary "requires" / dependancies and ordering of execution.

maybe there is some more context to your question you can share?

Comment: I added some more info